# Accord avec "une centaine"

Tags: accord, nombres, noms-collectifs

Quelle est la forme correcte:

> - Une centaine de manifestants est descendue dans la rue
> - Une centaine de manifestants sont descendus dans la rue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux sont possibles, le sens est légèrement différent. L'accord met en relief le mot auquel on veut donner de l'importance.

> Une centaine de manifestants sont descendus dans la rue.

Une centaine est alors une quantité approximative constituée d'éléments. L'accord avec le pluriel met en relief ces éléments. Le sens de la phrase pousserait ici au pluriel : ce sont les personnes qui sont descendues.

> Une centaine de manifestants est descendue dans la rue.

Le singulier reflète une quantité précise, met en valeur le groupe et rend moins l'effet de multitude.

Changeons légèrement l'exemple.

> - Une centaine de manifestants ont demandé à rencontrer le ministre.

Pas d'unité, chacun ayant pu faire sa demande séparément.

> - Une centaine de manifestants a demandé à rencontrer le ministre.

Implique qu'une seule et même demande a été faite par le groupe, le singulier met en relief leur union, ils font bloc face au ministre.

Voir ce que dit [la BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2933) à ce sujet.